# My program keeps looping and I don't know why (c++)

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in programming and I am currently trying to code things myself and I encountered a question that tells me to let a user choose from number 1-12 and it will display the month it represents (ex. 1=January) using while and switch loops. I'm now so brain dead need help.

edit: it loops if I entered a wrong input like putting a or 99.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
   
    int months = 0;
    cout << "Enter a number from 1-12 (or Q to quit):   " << endl;
    cin >> months;
while (months != 'Q')
{
switch (months){
                case 1:
                    cout << "January" << endl;
                    break;

                case 2:
                    cout << "February"<< endl;
                    break;

                case 3:
                    cout << "March" << endl;
                    break;

                case 4:
                    cout << "April" << endl;
                    break;

                case 5:
                    cout << "May" << endl;
                    break;

                case 6:
                    cout << "June" << endl;
                    break;

                case 7:
                    cout << "July" << endl;
                    break;

                case 8:
                    cout << "August" << endl;
                    break;

                case 9:
                    cout << "September" << endl;
                    break;

                case 10:
                    cout << "October" << endl;
                    break;

                case 11:
                    cout << "November" << endl;
                    break;

                case 12:
                    cout << "December" << endl;
                    break;
                default:
                    
                     {
                           cout <<"You've entered an invalid response. Please only select from numbers 1- 12.\n"; 
                           break;
                     }
}
                        }

//I hve no idea what to do here

return 0;

}
```

Comment: you seem to want `months` to be a `char` and an `int`. You need to decide for one

Comment: You should also refer to a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) which are also available as PDFs for free.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indent the code consistently. That will make it easier to read and understand it.

Comment: `while (months != 'Q')` - Nothing in the loop ever *modifies* `months`.  So if it doesn't equal `'Q'` right away then it will *never* equal `'Q'`.

Comment: All possible inputs need to either be of type `int` (the easier approach for OP), or of type `std::string`. This is because we are dealing with possible double-digit numbers and *some* symbol that should signify that we want to quit.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: And if you enter a valid moth, it does not loop?

Answer (score 4):

Two issues in your code:

First you read user input once outside of the loop. When the loop is executed once then it is executed forever, because the condition never changes. Move reading input inside the loop.

Second, you mixed up characters, `char`, and integers ,`int`. `'Q'` is a character literal, its a `char`. `1`,`2`, etc are integer literals, they are `int`s.

`char` is in fact also a number type, but specifically with input and output `char` is treated differently, because the "numbers" are treated as representations of characters. A common encoding is ASCII.

Pop quiz: What do you have to enter to make this code print `foo` on the console:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    if (x == 'Q') std::cout << "foo\n";
}
```

Answer: It depends. With the usual ascii encoding `'Q' == 81` so you need to enter `81` to make `x` equal to `'Q'`.

`std::cin >> x` reads an integer. If the user enters `Q` then reading an `int` will fail. `std::cin` will be in an error state and `x` will get `0` assigned.

Decide for one: Use an `int` then you cannot read user input `Q`. Or use `char` then you need to compare the input against the characters `'1'`,`'2'` etc.

Alternatively read a `std::string` and parse the input to see if it is a character or a number.

Comment: @R-301 if it is confusion you need to ask or tell me what specifically is confusing, only then I can clarify

Comment: Why do we need to change it from int to char? I mean we ask the user a "number" and not a char right?

Comment: @R-301 i did not say that you *need to* change it from int to char. I only said if you want to read a `Q` from user input then that wont work with `int`, because `Q` is not an integer

Comment: @R-301 in your code `cin >> months;` tries to read an integer from stdin. If the user enters something else than an integer then reading an integer fails

Comment: ohh now I got it. I have edited my code now I don't get why my code loops if the user inputs wrongly. Is there a fix?

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the input inside the while loop not outside it !
because the while loop depends on what the user will write
so you just need to correct it to this form

```
while (months != 'Q')
{
    cout << "Enter a number from 1-12 (or Q to quit):   " << endl;
    cin >> months;

}
```

Update :
if the user writes an invalid input your program will go inside an infinite loop again so you should think about how to terminate it immediately after an invalid input

Comment: Good sir! Your "update" is what making me go mad. It keeps looping. I thought break would suffice or is it not?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you used `while (months != 'Q')`, not `if (months != 'Q')`. The compiler will always loop the `while` loop since `months` is always not equal to Q. Also, `months` is an `int`, i.e. inputting `Q` (this is not int) will crash your code, so you might want to modify it. You can either change `Q` into an int, or use `char month` and compare with `'1', '2'` etc.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int months;
    cin >> months;
    while (months != 'Q') {
        cout << "Enter a number from 1-12 (or Q to quit):   " << endl;
        switch (months){
            case 1:
                cout << "January" << endl;
                break;

            case 2:
                cout << "February"<< endl;
                break;

            case 3:
                cout << "March" << endl;
                break;
            //etc. (i'll shorten the code here)

            default: 
                cout << "Your input is invalid. Please only input numbers 1-12.\n"; 
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

PS: Please indent your code properly. You do not want your code to be a mess.

Comment: Noted! But how will you code it in for? Is while bad in this situation?

Comment: If you are just receiving 1 input, `if` would be enough. However, if you have multiple inputs, add `cin >> month` at the end of the `while` loop.

Comment: @R-301 i see that you stated if you entered a wrong input it will loop infinitely. Is it only if you enter a wrong input will it loop infinitely or does it happen to each case?

Comment: only when the user inputs the wrong input then it will loop indifenitely. If I type the right things it will print just what I wanted but it will terminate the program

Comment: Did you edit your code? I see that it has the same problem of looping infinitely no matter what input in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Let's rename the variable and use a lookup table (array).

```
static const char *    month_names[] = 
{
    "No Month as 0",
    "January", "February", "March", "April",
    "May", "June", "July", "August",
    "September", "October", "November", "December"
};
int month_index = 0;
std::cout << "Enter month number: ";
std::cin >> month_index;
if ((month_index > 0) && (month_index < 12))
{
    std::cout << "Month name is: " << month_names[month_index] << "\n";
}
else
{
    std::cerr << "Invalid month number\n";
}
```

In the case of mapping a number to a name, arrays work very well.  You can also search the array for the month name and the index will be the month number.